# clearTimeout not working in javascript autocomplete script

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am using the following code as part of an autocomplete script to avoid hammering the server with every keystroke:

```
var that = this;

textInput.bind("keyup", function() {

    clearTimeout(that.timer);

    that.timer = setTimeout (that.doStuff(), 2000);

});
```

Unfortunately, this does not clear the old timers.  They still all execute.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to use:

```
that.timer = setTimeout (that.doStuff, 2000);
```

instead of:

```
that.timer = setTimeout (that.doStuff(), 2000);
```

Otherwise, doStuff will be called immediately.

Comment: Yup, that did it.  (Bonking head.)  Thanks!