# Creating a timer to check if user is typing

Tags: jquery, ajax, timer, keystroke

I need to check if user is typing or not before i send an ajax request so my server is not hammered with every stroke, can someone guide me on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [debouncing](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#debounce)/[throttling](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle). [`Underscore.js`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) has useful functions for it.

```
$('#field').on('keyup change', _.debounce(function() {
    // your ajax call
}), 2000);
```

This code would wait 2s after the last change before running your function.

Comment: i was thinkin something like
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618865/cleartimeout-not-working-in-javascript-autocomplete-script

Comment: It basically does the same, but you don't have to deal with the details but can use high-level functions.

Comment: my ajax request is not run with that ^